# Referring to locally stored CSS files in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, createelement

I'm working on an ASP.NET application. I have used the Highcharts JS library. 
Now in some of the JS files which come with the Highcharts library contains refrences to external site. For e.g.)

```
Highcharts.createElement('link', {
    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,600',
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css'
}, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
```

This createElement is called by another JS file of the Highcharts library itself.
For e.g.)

```
createElement = Highcharts.createElement
```

Now I have locally saved the files being refrenced by the href and included them in my project solution.
My question is how can I make the createElement to refer the locally saved file instead of pointing to the web.

This is how my directory structure looks like :

```
- XYZProject

     -Scripts

          - Highcharts

                  - Style - (Here I have saved all the CSS files which were being refrenced in the createElement

                         - themes (Contains all the library files and contains the above mentioned code)
```

So suppose I have file named **abc.css** for the above refrenced site in href in my **Style folder**. How can I make the files in themes folder to refer **abc.css**  ?

Comment: You would put `abc.css` in your `/style` folder and change the `href` property in `createElement()` to be the local path, like `/style/abc.css` or whatever

Comment: Try this "XYZProject/Scripts/Highcharts/Style/themes /abc.css"